# Only Deleting item from frontend not from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

i,m making a simple CRUD app using **Vue.js as frontend Nodejs as backend and MongoDB as database** . i have a delete function , but the problem is that it only delete Customer from frontend not from database , when i refresh the page to see **All Customers** after deletion , the customer again appear on frontend .. **Below is my Delete Function**

````
            {
               let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/Customer/delete/'+id;
              this.items.splice(id, 1);
               this.axios.get(uri);
            }```

                 //AND HERE IS MY BACKEND API FOR DELETE Customer

app.post('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        Customer.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) res.json(err);
            else res.json('Successfully removed');
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            response: "Invalid ID"
        })
    }
});```
````

Comment: You're making a get request to a post endpoint `app.post('/delete/:id'`. You should change axios.get to axios.post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a get request to a post endpoint `app.post('/delete/:id'`. You should change axios.get to axios.post and also, you should wait for success confirmation before taking out the item on your frontend.

```
   {
      let uri = 'http://localhost:3000/Customer/delete/'+id;
      try{
         this.axios.post(uri).then(()=>{
            this.items.splice(id, 1);
         });
      }catch(error){
         console.log('An error occured!');
      }
   }

   //AND HERE IS MY BACKEND API FOR DELETE Customer

app.post('/delete/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        Customer.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) res.json(err);
            else res.json('Successfully removed');
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            response: "Invalid ID"
        })
    }
})
```